# Loading file into dictionary splitting into key value pair

Tags: c#, dictionary, keyvaluepair

Hello I am having a problem I have created a dictionary with key-value pairs and successfully saved to text file issue I am having now is I want to edit key-value pairs but don't want to save the whole file each time as there are like 1000 lines

is there any way to save to a file and read certain keys for editing because want to change certain keys after adding keys and pairs to a text file but also need to miss out the first 4 lines because

they are not key-value pairs files I have generated so far

[File Saved](https://paste.md-5.net/rapilefade.bash)

and in all this there are 2 weapon files saved one normal one upgraded the revolver is upgraded but the issue im having here is im not sure how to read the file back in and edit only couple of lines

like for example one of the lines i want to add are

ammoName
displayName

on both normal and upgraded i have text boxes in-application and a save button but not sure how to load it up i have tryied the following code

```
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + "\\test.gdt");
        var bo3template = lines.Select(l => l.Split(' ')).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

but the 1st 4 lines ruin it because it's not the part of the key-value pair that is the endient of the file any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance elfenliedtopfan5

Comment: If this is completely your own application, and own file format? Why not change how you save/manipulate the data?

Comment: The only way to edit a line in a line-delimited file is to rewrite the whole file. There is no way to shift contents over to make room, for example, if a new value is longer than the old value. With only 1,000 lines, this is trivial for modern hardware, so I wouldn't think twice about it. But if you really want to be able to edit lines in place, you will have to switch to a different format, e.g. fixed-width fields, which would allow you to use [Seek](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?view=netframework-4.8) to cursor to a particular item and overwrite it.

Comment: @lcepickle its my own application but the file format is not mine it come form a game so needs to stay in the format giving that is the issue i am having i have a template for all the key and values just unsure how to edit certain areas

Comment: To skip the 1st 4 lines: `var bo3template = lines.Skip(4).Select(l => l.Split(' ')).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);`